# Find all files where no part of the path of the file is a symbolic link

Tags: linux, shell, symlink

Is there an easy way to find all files where no part of the path of the file is a symbolic link?

Comment: The title implies a different question then the question itself. Please adjust.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short:

```
find myRootDir -type f -print
```

This would answer the question.

Care to not add a slash at end of specified dir ( not `myRootDir/` but `myRootDir` ).

This won't print other than real files in real path.
No symlinked file nor file in symlinked dir.

But...

If you wanna ensure that a specified dir contain a symlink, there is a litte bash function to could do the job:

```
isPurePath() {
    if [ -d "$1" ];then
        while [ ! -L "$1" ] && [ ${#1} -gt 0 ] ;do
            set -- "${1%/*}"
            if [ "${1%/*}" == "$1" ] ;then
                [ ! -L "$1" ] && return
                set -- ''
              fi
          done
      fi
    false
}

if isPurePath /usr/share/texmf/dvips/xcolor ;then echo yes; else echo no;fi
yes

if isPurePath /usr/share/texmf/doc/pgf ;then echo yes; else echo no;fi
no
```

So you could *Find all files where no part of the path of the file is a symbolic link* in running **this** command:

```
isPurePath myRootDir && find myRootDir -type f -print
```

So if something is printed, **there are no symlink part !**

Comment: Of course, but this fails if there's already a symlink in `myRootDir` `:-(`.

Comment: Hi @gniourf_gniourf, if `myRootDir` is a symlink, nothing will be printed, If is located in a higher symlink, a supplementary check have to be done... This could be made with this simple check routine ;-)

Comment: I like my check routine better `;-)` (yours has 2 subshells and a 2 forks for _each_ component of the path).

Comment: But the OP is not really clear about what he's really trying to achieve anyways.

Comment: Did you prefer this version *without any fork*?

Comment: I don't like this version with an infinite loop if path doesn't start with a `/`. Try your command: `isPurePath .` surprise! `:-(`

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf `isPurePath .` could alway answer `true` as `.` **is** a real path. For relative consideration, will use `realpath`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script : (copy/paste the whole code in a [shell](/questions/tagged/shell))

```
cat<<'EOF'>sympath
#!/bin/bash

cur="$1"
while [[ $cur ]]; do
    cur="${cur%/*}"
    if test -L "$cur"; then
        echo >&2 "$cur is a symbolic link"
        exit 1
    fi
done
EOF
```

`${cur%/*}` is a bash [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe)

**EXAMPLE**

```
chmod +x sympath
./sympath /tmp/foo/bar/base
/tmp/foo/bar is a symbolic link
```

Comment: Hey, you wrote a beautiful infinite loop!

Comment: Thank you, it works. However, when I combine it with find like here:
find . -ctime 0 -type f -exec sympath {} \;
I get
$ find: 'sympath': No such file or directory
What I am missing?

Comment: Still infinite loop `:-(`. Also you'll have surprises with copy/pasting... `:-(`

Comment: Added single quotes to _here-doc_. There's no infinite loops. Works as a charm.

Comment: Infinite loop if path doesn't start with `/`. I thought you'd see it after **2** warnings. `:-(`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any *easy way*, but here's an answer that fully answers your question, using two methods (that are, in fact, essentially the same):

### Using an auxiliary script

Create a file called `hasnosymlinkinname` (or choose a better name --- I've always sucked at choosing names):

```
#!/bin/bash

name=$1
if [[ "$1" = /* ]]; then
    name="$(pwd)/$1"
else
    name=$1
fi

IFS=/ read -r -a namearray <<< "$name"

for ((i=0;i<${#namearray[@]}; ++i)); do
   IFS=/ read name <<< "${namearray[*]:0:i+1}"
   [[ -L "$name" ]] && exit 1
done

exit 0
```

Then `chmod +x hasnosymlinkinname`. Then use with `find`:

```
find /path/where/stuff/is -exec ./hasnosymlinkinname {} \; -print
```

The scripts works like this: using `IFS` trickery, we decompose the filename into each part of the path (separated by the `/`) and put each part in an array `namearray`. Then, we loop through the (cumulative) parts of the array (joined with the `/` thanks to some `IFS` trickery) and if this part is a symlink (see the `-L` test), we exit with a non-success return code (`1`), otherwise, we exit with a success return code (`0`).

Then `find` runs this script to all files in `/path/where/stuff/is`. If the script exits with a success return code, the name of the file is printed out (but instead of `-print` you could do whatever else you like).

### Using a one(!)-liner (if you have a large screen) to impress your grand-mother (or your dog)

```
find /path/where/stuff/is -exec bash -c 'if [[ "$0" = /* ]]; then name=$0; else name="$(pwd)/$0"; fi; IFS=/ read -r -a namearray <<< "$name"; for ((i=0;i<${#namearray[@]}; ++i)); do IFS=/ read name <<< "${namearray[*]:0:i+1}"; [[ -L "$name" ]] && exit 1; done; exit 0' {} \; -print
```

### Note

This method is 100% safe regarding spaces or funny symbols that could appear in file names. I don't know how you'll use the output of this command, but please make sure that you'll use a good method that will also be safe regarding spaces and funny symbols that could appear in a file name, i.e., don't parse its output with another script unless you use `-print0` or similar smart thing.

Comment: `$ bash -n ./hasnosymlinkinname`    
`./hasnosymlinkinname: line 13: syntax error: unexpected end of file`

Comment: @nickm After a bad edit, the script got screwed up. I fixed it.